# Docker Containers in Kubernetes pod not communicating

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have 2 docker containers, one is running a flask server and the other is running an angular app. When I run both containers on my local system they have no trouble communicating within localhost but when I push these containers into a kubernetes pod, I get the connection refused message. Can anyone please explain what I might be doing wrong within kubernetes?

Comment: You need to run the 2 containers inside the same pod. Or configure the services with a proper hostname instead of localhost.

Comment: Or do you mean, you can't access your app from outside the pod?

Comment: How many pods are you running?

Comment: I currently have 2 containers running in the same pod. When I run both containers on my local system there is no problem when it comes to communication within the localhost. I'm able to open both application containers in the single pod but there is no communication. To my understanding, the containers in a pod share a localhost, right?

Comment: What is your deployment yams file? Looks like it is something to do with how you access Vs how you exposed the service/ports.

Comment: I posted a picture of my pod and service setup yaml files. @techusersoma

Answer (score 1):

- containers within the same pod share the same network namespace so there should be no issue for them to communicate over localhost , but anway in this case you should run them on separate pods
- when you run two apps on different pods , they will need to communicate over pod IPs , Or you will need to expose them over service of type ClusterIP, or NodePort or Loadbalancer

In this case you can run them on separate pods and use cluster DNS service discovery. DNS-based service discovery provides a flexible and generic way to connect to services across the cluster.

Details:

[Kubernetes service discovery by example](http://kubernetesbyexample.com/sd/)